# Topologize $R((t))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, laurent-series

Let $R$ be a topological ring such that the topology is *not* discrete. Then the ring of Laurent power series $R((t))$ can be defined in the following way:

$$R((t))=\varinjlim_{r}t^r R[[t]]=\varinjlim_{r}\varprojlim_{m}\frac{t^rR[[t]]}{t^{r+m}R[[t]]}\,.$$

Since $ \frac{t^rR[[t]]}{t^{r+m}R[[t]]}\cong \oplus^m R$, we can start with the product topology on the right of the above equation and through an ind-pro process we can construct a topology on $R((t))$. It was proven that with such a topology $R((t))$ is not a topological ring anymore since the multiplication is not continuous as function in two variables.

In  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132650/topology-on-rt-why-is-it-always-the-same), it is clear that the subspaces $t^m R[[t]]$ are not open in $R((t))$. Are they closed? Moreover, what is a local basis for $R((t))$? Is there a way to express it explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the topology on $R$ is $T_0$ (which to me is part of the definition of "topological ring"), then $t^mR[[t]]$ is closed in $R((t))$.  Indeed, to check that it's closed, you just have to check that its intersection with $t^rR[[t]]$ is closed for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}$.  The space $t^rR[[t]]$ just has the product topology when you identify it with $R^\mathbb{N}$ via its coefficients, and $t^mR[[t]]$ consists of those elements which have vanishing coefficients corresponding to powers of $t$ less than $m$.  This is just the subset of $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ on which certain coordinates are $0$, which is closed in the product topology as long as $\{0\}$ is closed in $R$.

I would not expect there to be a nice local basis for $R((t))$; direct limits of non-open inclusions of spaces usually don't have nice local bases.  For instance, if $R$ is $T_0$ and not discrete, the space $R((t))$ is not sequential and in particular cannot have a countable local basis.  Here's a sketch of the proof: there must be a net converging to $0$ which is eventually not contained in any single $t^rR[[t]]$, since $R$ is not discrete so every neighborhood of $0$ must intersect $R\setminus t^rR[[t]]$ for all $r$.  But there is no sequence converging to $0$ which is eventually not contained in any $t^rR[[t]]$, since any set which contains only finitely many points in each $t^rR[[t]]$ is closed.

Comment: One simple question: why is it enough to prove that the intersection of $t^m R[[t]]$ and $t^r R[[t]]$ is closed in $t^r R[[t]]$ for any $r$? (Of course for $r\ge m$ this is trivial).

Comment: That's the definition of the direct limit topology.  A set is open (or closed) iff its preimage in each term of the limit is open (or closed).

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, Are the spaces $t^rR[[t]]$ free $R[[t]]$-modules of rank $1$?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius: Yes, they are freely generated by $t^r$.

Comment: When you write $R((t))=colim_{r\geq0} t^{-r}R[[t]]$, do you use the fact that every $R[[t]]$-module is the colimit of its finitely generated $R[[t]]$-submodules? Or put in another way, where do you get the $R[[t]]$-module isomorphism $R((t))=colim_{r\geq0}t^{-r}R[[t]]$ from?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius: This is just the fact that $R((t))$ is the union of the nested sequence of submodules $t^{-r}R[[t]]$.  Whenever a module is the union of a nested sequence (or more generally, directed family) of submodules it is their colimit.

Comment: Right, I understand. What is the official definition of a "nested sequence of submodules": "$\cdots\supset  t^{-r}\mathbb C[[t]]\supset t^{-r+1}\mathbb C[[t]]\supset\cdots\supset\mathbb C[[t]]$?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius: That's correct.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Thank you.

Comment: The above argument for nested sequences does not depend on the type of chains -whether they are ascending or descending-right? For instance, if $M$ is a $\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_1]]$-module and $\mathfrak{m}=(t_1, ..., t_n)$ is its maximal ideal, we have a descending filtration $M\supset M\mathfrak{m}\supset\dots M\mathfrak{m}^p\supset\dots$ and we still have a nested sequence of submodules. Ergo, $M=colim_{p\geq0} M\mathfrak{m}^p$, correct?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius:  Yes, but in that case it's trivial since $M$ itself is the greatest element of the chain.

Comment: Ok, if we set $p\leq 0$, then we have an ascending chain of modules  $\dots\subset\mathfrak{m}^{-p}M\subset\mathfrak{m}^{-p+1}M\subset\dots\mathfrak{m}M\subset(1)=M$. Since $M$ is attained, we again have $M=colim_{p\leq0}\mathfrak{m}^{-p}M$? It is again trivial, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, Since this post is closest to what I am interested in and I see that you understand this topic, I will try to ask here. Is the completion of the tensor product $V[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}\mathbb C((t))$ with respect to the (t)-adic topology on the $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module $V[[t]]$ and the topology $(t^n\mathbb C[[t]])$ of $\mathbb C((t))$ trivial? That is what I get at least. Furthermore, aren’t the sets $t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$ open in $\mathbb C((t))$, too?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of all the definitions you're using there.  I would recommend posting a new question with all the details.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I posted this question two days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555264/completion-of-a-scalar-extension-in-the-metric-topology. It is the same as the one in the comments.