# Completion of a scalar extension in the metric topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, tensor-products, formal-completions

Let $V$ be a complex vector space (not necessarily finite dimensional). Let $V[[t]]\cong V\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[[t]]$ be the completion of $V\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[[t]]$ with respect to the $(t)$-adic topology on $\mathbb C[[t]]$. Let $K:=\mathbb C((t))$ be the field of formal Laurent series. I would like to know what the completion of the tensor product $V[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K$ with respect to the $(t)$-adic topology on $V[[t]]$ and the topology $\{t^i\mathbb C[[t]]\}$ on $K$ is. I come up with the result zero but I do not believe that zero is what should come out. So maybe I have made a mistake.

Here is my computation:
$$V[[t]]\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K=\lim_{i, j}(V[[t]]/(t^i)\otimes_{\mathbb C[[h]]}K/t^j\mathbb C[[t]])\\
=\lim_{i, j}\frac{V[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]} K}{t^iV[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K+ V[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}t^j\mathbb C[[t]]}\\
=\lim_{i}\frac{V[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K}{t^iV[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K}\\
=\lim_i\frac{V[[t]]}{(t^i)}\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]} K\\
=0.$$

Comment: What is your definition of the completion of a tensor product with respect to topologies on the factors?

Comment: I am using the following definition: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU. In particular, I am applying the $(t)$-adic topology $\{t^iV[[t]]\}$ on the $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module $V[[t]]$ and the $\{t^j\mathbb C[[t]]\}$-topology on the field of formal Laurent series $K$. My computation yields $0$ but this contradicts texts I have seen where it should give something along the lines of $V((t))$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that with your definition you get $0$.  If you see people talking about getting a completion of $V((t))$ they are presumably using a different topology on the tensor product from yours, probably the one generated by neighborhoods of $0$ of the form $t^iV[[t]]\otimes t^j\mathbb{C}[[t]]$.

To give some intuition for why this should be sensible, your topology corresponds to saying that $x\otimes y$ is small if either $x$ or $y$ is small, whereas that topology would correspond to saying $x\otimes y$ is small if both $x$ and $y$ are small.  But if the potential size of $y$ is unbounded (as is the case for $y\in\mathbb{C}((t))$ when $y$ could be $t^{-n}$ for arbitrarily large $n$), you shouldn't expect $x\otimes y$ to be small just because $y$ is small.  Saying that $x\otimes y$ is small when $x$ is small just ends up meaning that *everything* is arbitrarily small, and so becomes $0$ in the completion.

Comment: If you look at the final two posts of user reuns in the comment section in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4532400/the-non-complete-extension-of-scalars-of-an-adically-complete-module-is-complete?noredirect=1#comment9583347_4532400, he seems to disagree. He does not obtain zero. Unfortunatelty, he disappeared and I cannot ask him. The broader question is how people extend the ground ring of a $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module $V[[t]]$ ($V$ is not necessarily finite dimensional) from $\mathbb C[[t]]$ to $K=\mathbb C((t))$? How do they get $V((t))$ from $V[[t]]$?

Comment: I start to think that people define $V((t))$ in the following way: $V((t))=\lim_{\leftarrow i}V[[t]]\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]} \mathbb C((t))/t^i\mathbb C[[t]]$. Meaning, they ignore the topology on $V[[t]]$. Of course, it is not clear why $\lim_i\mathbb C((t))/t^i\mathbb C[[t]]\cong\mathbb C((t))$, but apparently, this is assumed so in the community.